# "There was an error adding the redirect. Redirecting will cause a redirection loop"

Tags: redirect, cpanel

I am getting this error in cpanel in the Add Redirect section after creating an add-on domain:

```
There was an error adding the redirect. Redirecting "https://example.com" 
will cause a redirection loop because "http://.*/", which is located at 
"/home/folder/", is above "https://example.com", which is located at 
"/home/folder/"
```

- Type = Permanent (301) redirection
- All Public Domains
- Redirects to: "https://addonDomain"
- Wild Card Redirect

Preferably through cpanel, the goal is to redirect only through 301 redirect, for SEO purposes, and redirect the primary domain to the add-on domain. How to fix this loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use via .htaccess

Edit with this code:

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Change yourdomain.com with your domain name. This work for me.